# Is there a way to programmatically access the parent zone of a custom web part?

Tags: web-part

I'm trying to create a web part that a user can add to a page and it will display a website in the entire viewing area. My web part wraps a page viewer web part, and it seems that I need to be able to resize the zone that it is in to be 100% height of the screen for this to work. That's what I hope anyway...

Is there a simple way to access the web part's parent zone within the object model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Set a static height to your web part.
2. Use jQuery in your web part to set the height of the parent container: http://api.jquery.com/parent/